# How to remove common element from sql union

Tags: sql, union

I've got the following table:

| issueid | parentid | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 13 | a |
| 13 | 16 | b |
| 14 | 21 | c |
| 15 | 23 | d |

Both issueid and parentid's are id's of the same entity. And I want to get a list of entity ids that are not in either of the columns.

E.g. I want the result set of (14, 21, 15, 23) when the input is 13 (Because 13 is on the first 2 rows).

```
SELECT issueid from links where parentid not in (13); -- This gives 13, 14, 15
UNION
SELECT parentid from links where issueid not in (13); -- This gives 13, 21, 23

-- UNION gives 13, 14, 15, 21, 23
```

But I want to remove 13 from the above result set. How can I do that?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have mentioned what I've tried, why are you trying to close down questions without providing any useful info? I tagged both cz I can use both depending on the needs.

Comment: Try UNIONing everything then removing 13.

Comment: @SimonGoater I've done the union, but how do I remove 13?

Comment: I don't think you are clear what you want. If you want the result set of (14, 21, 15, 23), meaning if 13 is in either column, exclude the other value too, then just put another clause on each of your selects so they both read WHERE parentid NOT IN (13) AND issueid NOT IN (13);

Comment: @S.Dan Why is it hard to add the used rmdbs? :-)  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Please don't add answers to the question itself - that's what you should use the answer section for. Also, answers might vary from database system to system, so tagging it with those you want to use is fine. It wasn't obvious from the post itself that you searched a solution that works in both worlds

Comment: Please tag your question with the *one* database you are running: mysql, postgresql, oracle, ...? They have different dialects and features, which could or could not be relevant for your use case.

Comment: @GMB I did! and people keep editing to remove them!

Comment: @S.Dan: because you tagged 2 different databases (mysql and Postgres). Please tag only one database.

Answer (score 1):

You can union two anti-joins. For example:

```
select issueid from links a
left join links b on b.parentid = a.issueid where b.parentid is null
union
select parentid from links a
left join links b on b.issueid = a.parentid where b.issueid is null
```

Comment: This is giving me 12, 14, 15, 16, 21, 23. I want the result set of (14, 21, 15, 23).

Comment: But this gave me an idea and found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by @The Impaler I found the solution as:

```
select a.issueid from links a
                           full outer join links b on b.parentid = a.issueid where b.parentid is null
                                                                                    and a.parentid not in (13)
union
select a.parentid from links a
                          full outer join links b on b.issueid = a.parentid where b.issueid is null
                                                                                   and a.issueid not in (13)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor tweak will fix it:

```
SELECT issueid FROM links WHERE parentid NOT IN (13) AND issueid NOT IN (13); -- This returns 14, 15
UNION
SELECT parentid FROM links  parentid NOT IN (13) AND issueid NOT IN (13); -- This returns 21, 23
```